# Сегодня вы выполнили 20 проверок в очереди на закрытие. Возвращайтесь через 2 часа, чтобы продолжить проверку

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

> [image: Очереди проверок]

Что имеется ввиду под "сегодня"? Последние 24 часа? 
Или в какие-то конкретные часы счётчик сбрасывается?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сегодня - это сутки по UTC. Текущее время по UTC можно посмотреть в достижениях:

[image: скриншот]